How can I scale text to always fit a fixed-size container?
I have a <div> that is always a certain width (100% of screen, screen is always 800px wide). Inside that div I place some text, but that text can change.
I want the entire text to always fit inside the container, by changing the font size. For example the images below; the top has font-size: 260px, the bottom one 60px.


I am fine with using a pure CSS solution, or a combination of CSS and JavaScript.
I found some solutions about CSS containers, but they work when changing the container size (which in my case is always the same). This question does not help me, because my container is always the same size. I want to scale the text based on the length of the text, not the size of the container. The text can be changed dynamically.
I also found measureText in JavaScript, but I fail to see how I can translate pixel size of a word/sentence to a font-size.
How can I scale my text in such a way it always fits?

It looks like you're not adjusting the height of the container. What should happen if the text is a single narrow character like I? To make that fill the container's width it would overflow vertically by several hundred percent. Or do you expect the container's height to constrain the text as well?

@Chris Right. A single narrow character I should scale its height to the container height.

If you're okay with CSS, JavaScript, and SVG, then you might be interested in the technique I use in BigAs.

e.g. Some long text that should fit

... and Short

@GrahamHannington I fixed it with just JavaScript. But as this is (wrongly) marked as duplicate, I cannot add my answer.
